# Can't install here-api-for-javascript from package.json

Tags: npm, here-api, heremaps

I add package as described in [docs](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.17.0/dev_guide/topics/get-started-bundling.html) in second point:

```sh
$ npm install @here/maps-api-for-javascript --save
```

After that I get in `package.json`:

```
//...
    "dependencies": {
        "@here/maps-api-for-javascript": "^1.17.2"
    }
//...
```

After some changes I deploy code to remote server and type:

```sh
$ npm install
```

and get error:

```sh
/...
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@here%2fmaps-api-for-javascript - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@here/maps-api-for-javascript@1.17.2' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

Comment: Do you have HERE registry configured on the remote server as well?

`npm config set @here:registry https://repo.platform.here.com/artifactory/api/npm/maps-api-for-javascript/`

Comment: Thanks for that. After adding registry when I run `npm run production` I get in console errors.
https://i.ibb.co/CVd78mk/Screenshot-2020-07-05-21-39-55.png

Comment: Is it only happening on the remote server or also locally? If so, what are the differences between those setups? If not, it would be helpful to see a *minimal* reproducible project, leaving out your application code but having HERE Maps API for JavaScript included and some sample code that calls it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using yarn (v3.2.4):
In this case, you must add the next code to your .yarnrc.yml

```yml
nodeLinker: node-modules
npmScopes:
  here:
    npmPublishRegistry: "https://repo.platform.here.com/artifactory/api/npm/maps-api-for-javascript/"
    npmRegistryServer: "https://repo.platform.here.com/artifactory/api/npm/maps-api-for-javascript/"
```

After, you can do Yarn install.